# Object doesn't get updated after calling SaveAsync on Parse Unity 1.6.2

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I have a column ("DataDict") storing type of Dictionary (let say the variable name is call "dataDict")

Recently I've updated to Parse Unity 1.6.2 and I found out that whenever I make an update to dataDict, it doesn't get updated to the server.

For example:

```
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = ParseUser.CurrentUser["DataDict"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
    dict["name"] = "something new";
    // after I call ParseUser.CurrentUser.SaveAsync()
    // the server should have updated the dictionary 
    // but it's no longer working as what I expected after I've updated to Parse 1.6.2
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

I noticed one of the keypoint that listed in the changelogs:

*Removed 'mutable containers' functionality, significantly enhances performance.*

Does this affected my codes? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by calling

```
ParseUser.CurrentUser["DataDict"] = dict;
```